# Accessing Components after creation win32 API C++

Tags: c++, winapi

Taking a liking to c++ and wanting to create a windows-like application I have decided to try win32. Now that is working out pretty decent (I think). Nevertheless I find myself with a problem.

I want to create an application that has 2 buttons. When 1 is pressed the other one is no longer visible (very usefull).

**The problem**

I cannot seem to access the buttons I have created in my application. How can I access the created button in the CALLBACK. I am pretty sure this is a rather noobish question but it will certainly help me advance.

**What have I done so far** (not including all code)

```
enum {
  IDBC_DEFPUSHBUTTON=200
};

//Prototype functions
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);
int OnCreate(const HWND,CREATESTRUCT*);
HWND CreateButton(const HWND,const HINSTANCE,DWORD,const RECT&,const int,const ustring&);
inline int ErrMsg(const ustring&);

//Main
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE,LPSTR pStr,int nCmd) {
   ...
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CREATE: //APP-CREATE
        return OnCreate(hwnd,reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam));
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam)) {
            case IDBC_DEFPUSHBUTTON: {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY: //APP-END
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
       return DefWindowProc(hwnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);  
    }
}
```

The onCreate-function creates all the buttons and works great together with the CALLBACK (The app actually quits when I click on the button! (Testing purpose)). But rather then having

> PostQuitMessage(0)

I would like something like:

> IDBC_DEFPUSHBUTTON.Visible = false;

The following code is the OnCreate-function and the CreateButton-function:

```
int OnCreate(const HWND hwnd,CREATESTRUCT *cs) {
    RECT rc={10,10,200,40}; //Position Rectangle
    CreateButton(hwnd,cs->hInstance,BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,rc,IDBC_DEFPUSHBUTTON,_T("DEFAULT PUSH BUTTON"));
    return 0;
}

//Button creation function
HWND CreateButton(const HWND hParent,const HINSTANCE hInst,DWORD dwStyle,const RECT& rc,const int id,const ustring& caption) {
    dwStyle|=WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE;
    return CreateWindowEx(0,_T("button"),caption.c_str(),dwStyle,rc.left,rc.top,rc.right,rc.bottom,hParent,reinterpret_cast<HMENU>(static_cast<INT_PTR>(id)),hInst,0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to access a control window. One is to save the `HWND` returned by CreateWindowEx and use it every time you need to access the control. The other is to call [`GetDlgItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you know the `HWND` of the parent window and the ID you assigned when you created the control, which will return the `HWND` of the control. Obviously it's easier just to save the original value since it won't change.

Comment: So for example, creating a vector of HWND and putting the buttons in there is the recommended approach?

Comment: @FlorisVelleman, if you have a fixed number of buttons it's more typical to create a variable for each one, but I think you have the idea.